# How to create a frequency table of all value pair combinations of values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, columnsorting

Say we have:

```
data = {'Column 1':     [ 1 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 3 , 2 , 3], 
        'Column 2':     [ 3 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 ,''], 
        'Column 3':     [ 3 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 3 , '',''],
        'Column 4':     [ 4 , 2 , 6 , 4 , 2 , '',''],
        'Column 5':     [ 1 , '', '', 4 , 2 , '',''],
        'Column 6':     [ '', '', '', '', 2 , '','']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I need to create a frequency table that shows all combinations of unique items in each row. They have to still be counted even if they are not in the same order.

```
co1 co2 co3 co4 co5 co6
 1   3   3   4   1
 3   2   2   2
 4   2   3   6
 1   3   1   4   4
 3   3   3   2   2   2
 2   3
 3
```

Result:

```
Combination    frequency
[3]            1
[2,3]          3
[1,3,4]        2
[2,3,4,6]      1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is remove empty strings per rows, convert to sets for unique values, sorting and convert to tuples, for possible counts by `Counter`, last convert tuples to lists and created `DataFrame`:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [tuple(sorted(set([y for y in x if y!= '']))) for x in df.values]

c = Counter(L)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Combination': list(map(list, c.keys())),
                  'frequency':list(c.values())})
print (df)
    Combination  frequency
0     [1, 3, 4]          2
1        [2, 3]          3
2  [2, 3, 4, 6]          1
3           [3]          1
```

Comment: Does this also work if there are more columns in the original dataframe that are not related to this?

Comment: @nielsen - Sure, some problem? E.g. empty values are missing values?

Comment: @nielsen - if empty values are missing values and want remove them `L = [tuple(sorted(set([y for y in x if y== y]))) for x in df.values]`

Comment: I have more columns than the ones above, and some of them also have values like 1, 2, 3. These get included in the table. How can I define that it explicitly applies to columns 1-6 and for columns 7+, the numbers don't get included in the "Combination"?

Comment: Nevermind, I just created a new dataframe with the subset of columns.